# Adding bottom border on pdf form fields

Tags: pdf, itext, acrobat, abcpdf, foxit

I have to insert a bottom border on some fields in my pdf editable form.

I would like to insert a row without to do it manually for each field:

[image: screenshot]

I don't know which solution can help me to do this (a program like acrobat or foxit, an external library as itext sharp or abcpdf)

Have anyone some idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a number of tools that can help you here. One thing to note is that you can't add just a bottom border to the field itself. Borders on fields go all the way around. Instead, you'll use the location of the field rectangle to add a line to the page content itself making it appear that the field has a bottom border. What programming skills do you have and what PDF editing application or libraries do you own?

Answer (score 0):

In Foxit PhantomPDF (which is paid software), you can open the Fields panel...
[image]

...use Shift+Click to select all of the fields in the list...

[image]

...right-click on one of them and select Properties...

[image]

...then click on the Appearance tab, set "Line Style" to "Underline", and set the Thickness and Border Color as desired.

[image]

The result:

[image]